# Python : Remove few string content from list using regex or logically

Tags: python

I have directory of text files, each line of the file is read as list element and stored in a list

```
list = ['abc','[','apple','banana','cucumber',']','efg','{','egg','[fff]','ginger }','end;','abc1','[','apple1','banana1','cucumber1',']','efg1','{','egg1','[fff1]','ginger1 }','end1;']
```

Now I want to only remove the content inside the stand alone square brackets from the files - looks like'[','apple','banana','cucumber',']' in my list ..rest to be kept untouched.. even the square bracket content inside curly brackets needs to be retained- looks like [fff] content in my list.

So i joined all the strings to apply regex operation -

```
newlist = newlist = [' '.join(list)]
print(newlist)
```

newlist looks like -

```
['abc [ apple banana cucumber ] efg { egg [fff] ginger } end; abc1 [ apple1 banana1 cucumber1 ] efg1 { egg1 [fff1] ginger1 } end1;']
```

Expected output using regex -

```
['abc  efg { egg [fff] ginger } end; abc1  efg1 { egg1 [fff1] ginger1 } end1;']
```

Pls pls help..

Answer (score 1):

This regex will remove the unwanted data per your requirements

```
import re

list = ['abc','[','apple','banana','cucumber',']','efg','{','egg','[fff]','ginger }','end;','abc1','[','apple1','banana1','cucumber1',']','efg1','{','egg1','[fff1]','ginger1 }','end1;']
newlist = newlist = [' '.join(list)]
newlist = [re.sub('\[ .+? \]', '', newlist[0])]
```

Comment: Thanks Joe perri,
I replaced ' ' with '__' while joining the list.. added the same in regex parameter..  is it correct?..

`newlist = ['__'.join(list)]
newlist1 =[re.sub('\[__.+?__\]','',newlist[0])]
newlist2 = newlist1[0].split('__')`

Comment: Yes that appears to do the same as before. Also list is a python keyword so you probably shouldn't use it as a variable name even though it works here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe Perri.. it worked.. if u dont mind could u pls explain how this regex works along with re.sub() function..

Comment: What would be the regex incase the square bracket position in my list changes like-
`mylist = ['abc','[apple','banana','cucumber]','efg','{','egg','[fff]','ginger }','end;','abc1','[','apple1','banana1','cucumber1',']','efg1','{','egg1','[fff1]','ginger1 }','end1;']`

Comment: you could try something like this but that gets rid  of the [fff]

    newlist = [re.sub('\[ *.+? *\]', '', newlist[0])]

Comment: yeah '[fff]' has to be retained.. so, regex works for this use case? or it has to be handled logically?

Comment: Thanks Joe for the support..can u pls help me achieve this logically in python..?

Comment: You need to learn how to make a regex then it will be easy. I learned using [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) site and then practiced doing [regex golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf)